# Converting Consumers to Functions

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Many lambdas for the `Function` interface take the form

```
t -> {
    // do something to t
    return t;
}
```

I do this so often that I have written a method for it like this.

```
static <T> Function<T, T> consumeThenReturn(Consumer<T> consumer) {
    return t -> {
        consumer.accept(t);
        return t;
    };
}
```

This enables me to do really nice things like this:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed('A', 'Z')
         .mapToObj(a -> (char) a)
         .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), consumeThenReturn(Collections::shuffle)))
         .forEach(System.out::print);
```

Is there another way to do conversions like this without relying on my own method? Is there anything in the new APIs I have missed that makes my method redundant?

Comment: I don't think there is: take a look at `Collectors.toList()` code for example, it does `(left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; },`. That's the problem of methods mutating their argument... (side-note, you can have `UnaryOperator<T>` instead of `Function<T,T>`)

Comment: I would rename your function to [`tee`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)).

Comment: Everything has been already said, but I am working on something that already does this. https://github.com/TouK/ThrowingFunction/ any input is appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many potentially useful methods that could be added to the `Function`, `Consumer` and `Supplier` interfaces. You give a good example (converting a `Consumer` to a `Function`) but there are many other potential conversions or utilities that could be added. For example, using a `Function` as `Consumer` (by ignoring the return value) or as a `Supplier` (by providing an input value). Or converting a `BiFunction` to a `Function` by supplying either value. All of these can, of course, be done manually in code or provided via utility functions as you've shown but it would arguably be valuable to have standardised mechanisms in the API, as exist in many other languages.

It is speculation on my part, but I would guess this reflects the language designers' desire to leave the API as clean as possible. However I'm intrigued by the contrast (as an example) to the very rich set of `Comparator` utilities provided by the language to reverse orders, compare by several criteria, deal with null values etc. These also could easily have been left to the user but have been supplied by the API. I'd be interested to hear from one of the language designers why the approaches to these interfaces seems so inconsistent.

Comment: Excellent point about the new stuff for `Comparator`. You can already treat a `Function` as a `Consumer` though just by passing `function::apply`. I guess ignoring the return value is slightly less weird than returning the first argument when there isn't a return value.

Comment: Another sounded example would be `CompletableFuture`, last time I checked it contained near 60 methods...

Comment: You have to consider that Comparator is a old interface that has evolved over time. The java8 otoh is the first release with functional interfaces.

Comment: @the8472 no I don't think that's correct. All of the methods I am referring to in `Comparator` were added in java 8 (they are defined as default which is only available in 8). Compare http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: True, but they're still growing APIs over time, for example `Optional` will gain the much-requested [`or`](http://download.java.net/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) method in 9. Anyway, one potential difference between Comparator and the abstract functional interfaces is that the possible number of conversions between functional interfaces, especially the multi-argument ones just explodes due to many different use-cases while Comparators have more specific, common uses.

Comment: A `Comparator` bears a certain *semantic* and all added methods address that semantic. In contrast, the types in the `java.util.function` package are generic and addressing the lack of true function types in Java. It’s reasonable to assume that the Java maintainers are reluctant about adding functional transformation methods into these interfaces, because they expect them to be addressed in a different, more general way in a future Java release (when true function types enter the stage)…

Comment: @Holger Is it a proposal to add function types in the near future?

Comment: @Paul Boddington: While it’s clear that function types are on the long-term list, I don’t know about a “near future”. Currently, I have the feeling that they won’t appear soon. But still, there are design decisions made today, recognizably motivated by the wish to keep the road open. So there are functional interfaces only added as actually needed today by, e.g. the Stream API, but nothing more and everything being somewhat minimalistic and I don’t expect them to grow much, because the obvious preference of the maintainers is the true functional direction.

Comment: @Holger I hope you're right. I share the same feeling as you regarding functions as first class citizens in the language, though it's just pure intuition on my part (or maybe desire?). Certainly the `java.util.function` package is quite minimalistic, as the stream API is. However, I will believe it when I see it... and first I'd need to see [specialization](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/218), otherwise the language would grow to a mess

Comment: I accepted, mainly because I strongly agree with your point about `Comparator`. `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()` seems particularly out of place. We still have no better way to initialise an `ArrayList` than `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(...))` yet they've added vast numbers of unnecessary convenience methods returning `Comparator`.

Answer (score 2):

Apache commons collections 4.x has what you're looking for, I think.  Its equivalents for `Function` and `Consumer` are `Transformer` and `Closure`, respectively, and it provides a way to compose them using `ClosureTransformer`

It is trivial to convert between equivalent functional types by invoking the SAM of one and assigning it to the other. Putting it all together, you can end up with a Java 8 `Function` in this manner:

```
Consumer<String> c = System.out::println;
Function<String,String> f = ClosureTransformer.closureTransformer(c::accept)::transform;
```

`c::accept` converts the Java 8 `Consumer` to an equivalent Apache Commons 4 `Closure`, and the final `::transform` converts the Apache Commons 4 `Transformer` to an equivalent Java 8 `Function`.