# Using functions returning void in Java 8 streams

Tags: java-8, return-value, reverse, java-stream, void

How can I use functions returning void in a stream? Given this example where a file containing Strings is read and the words are printed:

```
myFancyFile.lines()
            .map(line -> line.split(" "))
            .map(Arrays::asList)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

If I want the words to be reversed, I would use `Collections.reverse()`, but I can hardly insert that into the stream. I realize I can use a `Comparator` here with `sorted()`, this is just an example. I guess the only way to do this is using a Function?

I really can't see why this question should be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392228/converting-consumers-to-functions), it's a completely different topic about conveniently wrapping Consumers to Functions.

Comment: What exactly do you want to reverse? Answers below seem to reverse order of words within a line while keeping the order or lines. As such, reversing is an operation on a single stream element, which is OK. Given that streams are lazy by design, reversing the entire stream is hardly possible within a pipeline.

Comment: I believe it's an exact duplicate of the linked question. You are asking how to use a method that takes one argument and returns `void` instead of a `Function`, which can be a reference to a method that takes one argument and returns an object.

Comment: The fact that you cannot directly use consumers here should be hint enough to rethink your approach in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Use a lambda expression instead of a method reference.

```
myFancyFile.lines()
            .map(line -> line.split(" "))
            .map(array -> {
                List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
                Collections.reverse(list);
                return list;
            })
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`peek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-) method:

```
myFancyFile.lines()
            .map(line -> line.split(" "))
            .map(Arrays::asList)
            .peek(Collections::reverse)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Looks good, though according to the docs this is supposed to be used for debugging only, I wonder if this is the best practice for including side effects in streams. But I want side effects to be obvious like with `peek` instead of hiding them in some method reference, so this seems to be a good, yet non canonical solution.